# Apps in panel keep bouncing

Tags: gnome, icons, dock

I installed Ubuntu 23.04, and I also had the same issue on Ubuntu 22.04. The icons in the panel keep bouncing. When it bounces, it closes the right click and it is very CPU consumer such that the fan of my gaming laptop keeps working. How can I fix this?

To demonstrate the problem, please see [the following video 10 sec](https://jumpshare.com/v/6ir3b0jlcpSMUzLGjsEJ)

[image]

The **DG** (DataGrip) icon bounces twice.

---

Disabling GNOME JavaScript by [`gnome-extensions disable ding@rastersoft.com`](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/2087/desktop-icons-ng-ding/) fixed it for a while.

Comment: What happens if you change the theme (you would need a different Gnome-shell theme) with gnome-tweaks ?

Comment: well, disabling gjs solved the problem. h

Comment: Why you say you disable GNOME JS just by disabling _Desktop Icons NG (DING)_ extension? If just disabling that extension fixed the problem you should [file an issue](https://gitlab.com/rastersoft/desktop-icons-ng/-/issues/?sort=created_date&state=opened&search=bounce&first_page_size=20). Else, disabling all the extensions fix it? Also, `journalctl -xe` show something when this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade

dconf reset -f /org/gnome/
gnome-shell --replace
```

I had similar problem and one of my colleagues help me with it.

Comment: Or check the system log:

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Resetting the entire GNOME directory will have a huge side effect and doesn't address the root of the problem